# Is it considered bad practice to edit files in the src/test/resources folder

Tags: java, junit

**Source:** Java 8
**IDE:** Eclipse
**Testing:** JUnit
**Build Tool:** Maven
**Packaging:** WAR

I need to JUnit test my code that manipulates Excel files. I was planning to keep some sample Excel files the `src/test/resources` folder. Using `@Before` I would create a new folder inside the `src/test/resources`  (with a timestamp) and copy the sample Excel files in there. Then the tests would operate on those files and then remove the timestamp folder `@After` the tests.

**My questions are:**

1. It is bad practice to modify files in this directory considering it is part of the codebase?
2. Does this have implications when my code is running in CI using maven.
3. If the answer to 1 is Yes then are there advisable alternative approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bad practice.* Use the files in resources as **template**. That is copy them using

```
Path target = Files.createTemp...
Files.copy(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/..."), target);
```

In a temp directory results will at some future moment be cleaned up, if you would like so.

Under some circumstances instead of a temporary directoy one may write to the target build directory. For instance for your own maven reporting plugin. However for tests the above should do.

Answer (score 2):

> It is bad practice to modify files in this directory considering it is
>   part of the codebase?

Even if you change the content of "only" testing directory, it is not a good idea because you may produce side effects during test phase if your tests don't behave as they should (suppose they leave a test resource file not in the expected and original state).

> Does this have implications when my code is running in CI using maven.

I don't see why it would be more or less a problem in this environnement. The worst is I think in the development env as you may commit undesirable things if the test execution has produced side-effects.

> If the answer to 1 is Yes then are there advisable alternative
>   approaches.

Actually, you copy data in a new folder inside the `src/test/resources`.
What I propose you is simply copy data in a folder where you don't risk to create any side effect in the code  : `target/test-classes`.

The `test-classes` dir is not used for the packaging of the artifact.